# How to address remove_widget what widget to remove inside another layout in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am a beginner just learning coding and Python.
I am not able to remove a widget that I just have created.

I can still create new button. This is actually just little side test.

Eventually I want to have a scrollview where I can add and remove buttons. There are some *add/remove widget code snippets* but I must be able to add/remove widgets in another layout.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

KV = """
BoxLayout
    id:aaa
    Button
        text: 'Add'
        on_press: app.add_more()
        
    Button:
        text:'Remove'
        on_press: app.remove()
    BoxLayout:
        id:abc

"""

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)

    def add_more(self):
        print('wass')
        addbutton = self.root.ids.abc
        addbutton.add_widget(Button(text='hello'))

    def remove(self):
        print('hello')
        self.remove_widget(self.children[0])

MyApp().run()
```

I got this error message when clicking the remove button:

> MyApp' object has no attribute 'remove_widget'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## AttributeError

```
     self.remove_widget(self.children[0])
 AttributeError: 'MyApp' object has no attribute 'remove_widget'
```

### Root Cause

The App class inherited by MyApp, does not have the method, `remove_widget()`. Only a *root widget*, which usually has children that can have children of their own.

## Question

> remove widget inside another layout

### Solution

- Replace `self.remove_widget(...)` to `self.root.ids.abc.remove_widget(...)`
- Replace `self.children[0]` with `self.root.ids.abc.children[0]`
- Check that there are children inside the layout before we invoke `remove_widget()`

#### Snippets

```
def remove(self):
    print('hello')
    if len(self.root.ids.abc.children) > 0:   # check for children
        self.root.ids.abc.remove_widget(self.root.ids.abc.children[0])  # remove child FIFO
```

### [Kivy Widget » remove_widget()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/widgets.html#manipulating-the-widget-tree)

> Widgets in Kivy are organized in trees. Your application has a root
>   widget, which usually has [children](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.children) that can have [children](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.children) of
>   their own. Children of a widget are represented as the [children](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.children)
>   attribute, a Kivy [ListProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ListProperty).
>
> The widget tree can be manipulated with the following methods:
>
> [add_widget()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.add_widget): add a widget as a child
>   [remove_widget()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.remove_widget):
>   remove a widget from the children list
>   [clear_widgets()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.clear_widgets): remove
>   all children from a widget

Answer (score 0):

Since you load the layout as `self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)`, you can remove the first child with `self.root.remove_widget(self.root.children[0])`