# Kivy Three Buttons generated on pressing a Button. One of the New Buttons when pressed should remove All 3 New Buttons

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

In this code, On pressing button "CREATE", three buttons "Remove","Btn1","Btn2" are created... On pressing "Remove" button, all the three buttons ("Remove","Btn1","Btn2") should be removed.
I tried many ways but I can't find a way to make the new buttons accessible to other functions that are under the same class.

Main Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager

class Main(Screen):
    def remove(self):
        self.ids.Fl.remove_widget(Btnremove)
        self.ids.Fl.remove_widget(Btn1)
        self.ids.Fl.remove_widget(Btn2)

    def addme(self):
        Btnremove=Button(text="Remove",font_size=18,size_hint=(.2,.1),pos_hint={"center_x": .5, "center_y": .7})
        Btn1=Button(text= "Btn1",font_size=18,size_hint=(.2,.1),pos_hint={"center_x":.4,"center_y":.2})
        Btn2=Button(text="Btn2",font_size=18,size_hint=(.2, .1),pos_hint={"center_x": .6, "center_y": .2})
        self.ids.Fl.add_widget(Btnremove)
        self.ids.Fl.add_widget(Btn1)
        self.ids.Fl.add_widget(Btn2)
        Btnremove.bind(on_press=self.remove())

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass
kv=Builder.load_file("test2.kv")
screen=Manager()
screen.add_widget(Main(name="main"))
class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return screen
Test().run()
```

Kv Code:

```
<Main>:
    name: "main"
    FloatLayout:
        id: Fl
        Button:
            id: create
            text: "CREATE"
            size_hint: (.55,.175)
            pos_hint: {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5}
            on_press:
                root.addme()
```

Comment: if that layout contains only those three buttons, then use `self.ids.Fl.clear_widgets()`

Comment: But then wouldn't the main button also be removed... I need it to be a cycle... when I press the main button "CREATE" three new btns are created... On pressing one of the new btns "Btnremove"... only the 3 New buttons created will be removed not the main...

Comment: after removing all the buttons, just add the main button again.

Comment: My actual code is much more complex... but the functionality is the same... tats why I need it to work in the same way i've put... adding a button again dynamically wont accept the features i've put.. as far as i know it works only in the kv code

Comment: Just curious: What is the difference to your [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68781274/kivy-two-new-buttons-created-on-pressing-a-button-on-pressing-one-of-the-new-bu) asked ?

Comment: the method of the making the buttons are diff... here btns are created under a function ... which is more favourable for my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [answered solution of Parvat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68871103/5730279) iterates over all children (buttons) inside your widget and removes all of them, that have not the text `CREATE`. So it implicitly works without knowing the buttons created before.

### Considerations

Even if this is expected to work, but it does not really explain your issue here.
It works only, because it has **no knowledge of the buttons**. Only thing it assumes, that there is one **button `CREATE` to preserve** (not delete).
Unfortunately the `CREATE` button was defined even outside code in the config. If you change the text there (e.g. to `CREATE BUTTONS`), your function will not work as expected anymore.

### Issues spotted

#### Use Instance Variables instead

You claim that your `remove` method does not work as expected.
And further that you don't know how to **make buttons accessible to other functions**.

In you ***instance** method* `remove(self)` you're addressing the button objects (e.g. `Btnremove`) like they were global variables.

```py
def remove(self):
    self.ids.Fl.remove_widget(Btnremove)
    self.ids.Fl.remove_widget(Btn1)
    self.ids.Fl.remove_widget(Btn2)
```

But they aren't. They are local variables, only **visible inside** the other instance method `addme(self)`:

```py
def addme(self):
        Btnremove=Button(text="Remove",font_size=18,size_hint=(.2,.1),pos_hint={"center_x": .5, "center_y": .7})
        Btn1=Button(text= "Btn1",font_size=18,size_hint=(.2,.1),pos_hint={"center_x":.4,"center_y":.2})
        Btn2=Button(text="Btn2",font_size=18,size_hint=(.2, .1),pos_hint={"center_x": .6, "center_y": .2})
  chance
```

#### Bind a function by name only

Your bound action for `on_press` event was defined like calling a function, i.e. `self.remove()`. Instead define it as reference to the function/method by simply passing the name like `self.remove` (without parentheses!).

See Kivy's documentation on [`Button`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html):

> To attach a *callback* when the button is pressed (clicked/touched), use bind:
>
> ```py
> def callback(instance):
>     print('The button <%s> is being pressed' % instance.text)
>
> btn1 = Button(text='Hello world 1')
> btn1.bind(on_press=callback)
> ```

This `callback` is simply the method-name (without parentheses). In your case:

```py
# before: will result in `None` bound and raise an error when pressed
Btnremove.bind(on_press=self.remove())

# after: will call the function by name
Btnremove.bind(on_press=self.remove)
```

Congrats, you found the bug yourself and fixed it.

#### What happened before, why the error?

Because when binding and defining the callback as `on_press=self.remove()` the method is immediately called and returns `None` (the method does not return an object). Then `None` is bound instead of the function-reference.

So adversely two things happen that you did not expect:

1. you removed the buttons during binding (before button was pressed)
2. when button is pressed, the callback defined as `None` can not be called. Hence the error:

> AssertionError: None is not callable

### Accessing state or variables between instance methods

There are different ways to solve this (which have nothing to do with Kivy):

1. **add a parameter** (holding the buttons) to the method so you can pass over local variables as argument when calling
2. **add instance variables** (holding the buttons) so every *instance method* inside your class has access to them

#### Add Parameter to an Instance Method

```
# adding a parameter `widgets`
def remove(self, widgets):
    for w in widgets:
        self.ids.Fl.remove_widget(w)

# calling the method with argument
def addme(self):
    # omitted code
    buttons_to_remove = [Btnremove, Btn1, Btn2]  # creating a list with your buttons
    Btnremove.bind(on_press=self.remove(buttons_to_remove))  # pass the list as argument to the method
```

**⚠️ Warning:** This binding `on_press=self.remove(buttons_to_remove)` will not work, since a callback has to be passed as method-reference by name only. No custom arguments can be passed like `buttons_to_remove`. The only argument that is passed implicitly to the method by Kivy is `instance` as reference to the button instance itself.

#### Add Instance Variables

Over these instance variables (the *instance* scope is marked with prefix `self.`) we can share state inside the object. So we can share state between all *instance methods* because all have access to the instance object `self`. So they have also access to everything inside `self` like `self.buttons_to_delete`.

```
# accessing instance variable `buttons_to_remove`
def remove(self):
    # accessing the shared instance variable using instance-prefix `self.`
    for btn in self.buttons_to_remove:
        self.ids.Fl.remove_widget(btn)

# adding buttons to the instance-variable `buttons_to_remove`
def addme(self):
    # omitted code
    self.buttons_to_remove = [Btnremove, Btn1, Btn2]  # creating a list with your buttons
    Btnremove.bind(on_press=self.remove())  # the method has access to this list
```

**⚠️ Warning:** If you haven't declared the instance variable `self.buttons_to_remove` before (e.g. in constructor), and you now call `remove` before `addme`, then inside `remove` it will raise an error because your instance-variable does not yet exist and is unknown.

### Removing Widgets

A similar question was already asked and answered:
[How to address remove_widget what widget to remove inside another layout in Kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56183684/how-to-address-remove-widget-what-widget-to-remove-inside-another-layout-in-kivy)

The call of Kivy's `remove_widget` method is right, expects a **child** (of type `Widget` or here: `Button`) passed to it.

Like in this example from the docs about [`remove_widget`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.remove_widget):

```
>>> from kivy.uix.button import Button
>>> root = Widget()
>>> button = Button()
>>> root.add_widget(button)
>>> root.remove_widget(button)
```

Notice here, that the ***local** variable* `button` is visible & accessible to the method `remove_widget` because it's passed as argument.

Comment: Wow... Thanks a lot for taking your time to explain this...

Comment: Sry Again I executed it... Got a AssertionError: None is not callable... Any idea why?

Comment: I used your 2nd method, made some changes... def remove(self,widget): and Btnremove.bind(on_press=self.remove) Note: I removed the () in self.remove() and Its working...

Comment: @ZaynNaz: I didn't test my solution either and you found and solved my bug yourself ️ I will update my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can iter all the children of `float layout` in the `remove` function.

```
def remove(self):
    children = self.ids.Fl.children

    for btn in children:
        # if the button is not the create button
        if btn.text != "CREATE":
            self.ids.Fl.remove_widget(btn)
```

> ###### I have not tried that.